# Creating a record with an n:m relationship, using Sequelize, NodeJS, and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sequelize.js

**Update**: I've gotten a fair bit further. Please see the bottom of the post...

I'm working on a project that is based on the `sql-fullstack` yeoman generator, and have been using the included example code as a guide. Things have progressed smoothly, for the most part, but I'm now in a scenario where I have two tables/models with a bidirectional n:m relationship:

TaskGroup:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var TaskGroup = sequelize.define("TaskGroup", {
    taskGroupID: {
      field: "TaskGroupID",
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      field: "Name",
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
      field: "Description",
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    modifiedBy: {
      field: "ModifiedBy",
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
  });
```

and Task:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Task = sequelize.define("Task", {
    taskID: {
      field: "TaskID",
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      field: "Name",
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
      field: "Description",
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    isOnRunsheet: {
      field: "IsOnRunsheet",
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
    },
    modifiedBy: {
      field: "ModifiedBy",
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
  });
```

Relationships:

```
  // Tasks can belong to more than one group, and groups can belong to more than one task
  db['TaskGroup'].belongsToMany(db['Task'], {as: 'Tasks', through: 'TaskGrouping'});
  db['Task'].belongsToMany(db['TaskGroup'], {as: 'TaskGroups', through: 'TaskGrouping'});
```

On the client side, the user is able to create a new task and specify the associated task groups through a multiple select list. When the task is saved, I have both the task fields and an array of the associated task groups. A `post` is made with the request body containing this information, so that the server can create the task record.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get the record created. I've been through a number of iterations, and I'm at the point where I get what appears to be a reasonable exception - I'm just stumped as to what the "reasonable" thing to do is...

Exception:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeDatabaseError: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'TaskTaskID', table 'HelpCard
.dbo.TaskGrouping'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
    at Query.formatError (C:\Projects\helpcard2\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\query.js:215:10)
    at Request.userCallback (C:\Projects\helpcard2\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\query.js:66:25)
    at Request.callback (C:\Projects\node_modules\tedious\lib\request.js:33:27)
    at Connection.message (C:\Projects\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1179:27)
    at Connection.dispatchEvent (C:\Projects\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:519:45)
    at MessageIO.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:439:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
    at MessageIO.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at ReadablePacketStream.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\node_modules\tedious\lib\message-io.js:92:15)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
...
```

Here's the code on the client side:

```
$scope.createTask = function() {
  if($scope.newTask === '') {
    return;
  }
  $scope.newTask.modifiedBy = 'tkturney';
  var taskBundle = {
      task: $scope.newTask,
      taskGroups: $scope.selectedGroups
  };
  $http.post('/api/tasks', taskBundle);
  setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.currentTask = $scope.newTask;
    $scope.newTask = '';
    $scope.addingTask = false;
    refreshTasks();
  }, 250);
};
```

...and on the server side:

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  var task = Task(req).build(req.body.task);
  task.setTaskGroups(req.body.taskGroups);
  task
    .save()
    .then(function() {
      return res.status(201).json(task);
    })
    .catch(function (err){
      if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    });
};
```

I'm sure that I'm missing something obvious, but the documentation that I've found has been pretty light on a scenario like this. I would appreciate any guidance; I'm just getting into sequelize, and I feel that there are times that I may have bitten off more than I can chew... :)

**Update**: After taking a closer look at the SQL, I discovered that the exception was being thrown when trying to insert into the join table (TaskGroupings). It was trying to insert a NULL for the task's primary ID, which is generally not a good thing. Looking at the code, I realized that I was trying  to add the association before I had saved the record, leaving me with no PK. Moving the `task.addTaskGroups()` after the `save()` took care of that issue.

However, I also realized that I was passing an array of TaskGroup objects to the 'addTaskGroup()` call, instead of the actual IDs. So, I modified the client-side controller like so:

```
$scope.createTask = function() {
  if($scope.newTask === '') {
    return;
  }
  $scope.groupKeys = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.selectedGroups, function(taskGroup) {
    $scope.groupKeys.push(taskGroup.taskGroupID);
  });
  $scope.newTask.modifiedBy = 'tkturney';
  var taskBundle = {
      task: $scope.newTask,
      taskGroups: $scope.groupKeys
  };
  $http.post('/api/tasks', taskBundle);
  ...
```

When I look at the debugger, I can see everything in the `taskGroup` object, but `taskGroup.taskGroupID` is coming back as `undefined`, so I'm still getting an exception because I'm not passing the PKs for the other side of the association.

Does anything leap out as to what might be screwy with this code fragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, by changing the server-side controller from this:

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  var task = Task(req).build(req.body.task);
  task.setTaskGroups(req.body.taskGroups);
  task
    .save()
    .then(function() {
      return res.status(201).json(task);
    })
    .catch(function (err){
      if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    });
};
```

To this:

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  var task = Task(req).build(req.body.task);
  task
    .save()
    .then(function() {
      task.setTaskGroups(req.body.taskGroups);
      return res.status(201).json(task);
    })
    .catch(function (err){
      if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    });
};
```

That particular exception went away. The thing that I was missing (though it was staring me in the face) was the fact that there are two separate inserts happening - one for the task, and one for the association. I was thinking that I needed to set the association before saving the task, not realizing that setting that association caused another insert.

I still need to figure out why the PKs for the other side of the association aren't getting populated, but that's outside the scope of the original question...